# expand bash functions in find's exec parameter

Tags: bash, shell, find, expansion

How can I make `find` apply my shell's defined functions and aliases inside its *exec* parameter?

For example I have defined a function analogous to **bzip2** but using **7z**:

> function 7zip() { for f in $@; do  ls -alF "$f"; 7za a -t7z -m0=lzma
>   -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=64m -ms=on "$f.7z" "$f" && touch -r "$f" "$f.7z" && rm -fv "$f" && ls -alF "$f.7z"; done; }

When I find files older than 7 days to compress:

```
find . -mtime +7  -name "G*.html"   -execdir  7zip {}  +
```

Rather than expanding **7zip** it errors Command Not Found.

This is all inside a shell script.

Comment: Summing up some comments: 1. Define and `export -f 7zipi`  in `~/.bashrc`   2. Use the `find ... -exec bash -c "7zipi {}" +`

Comment: Wound up using `find . -mtime +7 -name "G*.html" -execdir bzip2 -9v {} \;` due to slightly better compression at those smaller file sizes, and .bz2 being an easier format to deal with in UNIX for unpacking later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four of these command works just fine with the function call. Adjust your find specs as need be.. They all cater for spaces in file names.  Personally, I can't see the point of shelling out to another bash instance, but I've included two versions which call bash.

```
IFS=$'\n'; f=($(find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "$USER.*")); f7zipi "${f[@]}"

IFS=; find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "$USER.*" | while read -r f ;do f7zipi "$f"; done 

IFS=$'\n'; bash -c 'IFS=; f7zipi "$@"' 0 $(find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "$USER.*")  

find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "$USER.*" -exec bash -c 'IFS=; f7zipi "$@"' 0 {} +;
```

---

What follows is how I've set up the function, using GNU bash 4.1.5 in Ubuntu 10.04

BTW. You should use `local f` in your function, so that it **does not clash** with the calling script's variable of the same name.

This is exactly what I added to my ~/.bashrc

```
function f7zipi() { 
    local f
    for f in $@; do 
        ls -alF "$f"
        7za a -si -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 \
        -md=64m -ms=on "$f.7z" < "$f" && 
            touch -r "$f" "$f.7z" && 
            rm -fv "$f" && 
            ls -alF "$f.7z"
    done
}
export -f f7zipi
```

When I only assign the above function into a terminal's bash command line, a script running from that command line fails when it calls the function...  If I further apply `export -f f7zipi` to that same command line.. then the script succeeds... However the scipt only works for that particular commandline session.

When the function and  export are included into `~/bashrc`, the script works every time, in any bash session..

This is the test script

```
#!/bin/bash
f=/tmp/$USER.abc
g=/tmp/$USER.lmn
rm -fv "$f" "$f".7z
rm -fv "$g" "$g".7z
printf 'abcdefg'>"$f"
printf 'lmnopqr'>"$g"
IFS=$'\n'; f=($(find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "$USER.*")); f7zipi "${f[@]}"
exit
```

Comment: You were going to illustrate how this works for `find`'s _-execdir_ or _-exec_, no?

Comment: @Marcos, no, it was William Pursell who suggested calling bash in a subshell in response to Nik O'Lai's comment.... I really only got involved in response to the *possible cause* of the function call error...

Comment: I have now added 4 ways to call a function with the output from `find`... Two method utileze `find -exec`

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive testing! BTW I switched to my earlier `7zip` function which by _not_ compressing from stdin ala `< "$f"` preserves the inner file's timestamp.  Also, turned out `bzip2 -9v` does slightly better with 1000+ html files of 60-400kb individually. 7z seems to beat it with larger/solid archives of many MBs.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a function definition with:

```
export -f 7zipi
```

but using an indentifier whose name begins with a number is asking for trouble.  Try changing the name to something sensible.  (eg "f7zipi", or "_7zipi")

Comment: Tried that, but still get `find: '7zipi': No such file or directory`

Comment: Defined, exported -f, and tried the _ version too: `find: '_7zipi': No such file or directory`

Comment: It works for me, but it will only work for the duration of that bash session... To make it permanent, add both the function definiton and the export line to your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: weird... it does not work for me, in bash v. 3.2.39 and find (GNU findutils) v. 4.4.0. Looks like this is a limitation of `find` that does not accept a function as --execdir argument.

Comment: @nik  Find is not invoking the command through bash.  Try -execdir bash -c 'zipi7 {}' \;

Comment: I use bash versions 4.2.8(1) and 4.2.10(1), on Ubuntus 10 and 11.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanx, it really works with explicit `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Being the impatient coder than I am, for now I changed it around to multiple lines with:

```
hitlist=$(find . -mtime +7  -name "G*.html")
7zipi $hitlist |awk ' !x[$0]++'
```

That *awk* bit at the end there btw is so that the output only prints lines not seen before yet, so that it doesn't clutter with a zillion lines of:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
Compressing  [Content]      
Everything is Ok
```

*NOT* really the answer though; I'd still like **find** to use my macros generally.

Comment: Check my comment to William Pursell's answer, which does work with one extra step.

Comment: @Peter.O Post your `bash -c` answer so I can mark as solution. That stuff already is in my `.bashrc` so close enough.

Comment: The method I used does not use `bash -c`.. I've posted it so you can compare it to what you have.

Comment: @Marcos Or just: `7zipi $(find . -mtime +7  -name "G*.html")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that not every `find` will accept a function as an argument for `--execdir`. It did not work for me either in the original form or using `export -f`.

However, if your make a script out of your function, it will work

```
find . -mtime +7 -name "G*.html" -execdir  /path/to/script_7zipi {} +
```

Comment: True.  I could just stick with the more portable `bzip2 -9v`, or hope some wrapper script eventually gets packaged into 7z for UNIX to make it act more like the legacy compressors used in pipes etc.